# Not secure No Data block Automation execution in chrome browser

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[image]

i used the above code in selenium 4.16.0, chrome-120.0.6099.217

```py
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service

service_obj = Service()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj)

driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you posted the full code, anyways you should also include a `Options()` object and **use the correct `Options` and `Service`** for your browser (imports).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options(), service=Service())
driver.get("https://google.com")
```